how to do something after kill terminal in vscode
When I run a task in vscode, how can I execute specific commands after I click the delete button(kill terminal)
for example.
when I run task A in vscode, I want to modify a charcater in a file with bat command after I kill the terminal, how can I do that?


This question doesn't make any sense. Why are you closing the terminal in the first place?

On Linux using a bash shell
You could use the trap functionality from your shell.
Ex. Using bash as shell, you could add to ~/.bashrc
trap "date >> /tmp/log.log" EXIT

This will write the current time to /tmp/log.log when you kill the terminal.
On Windows the default terminal should be powershell
Create a new profile script with New-item -type file -force $profile
or append to an existing one
"Autostart Profile ${PSScriptRoot}"

Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -SupportEvent -Action {
    date | Out-File -Append "${env:TEMP}\log.log"
}

Perhaps you need to allow the execution of the script.
Instructions can be found here Run Powershell script when you open Powershell
PS: Be careful:
The "X" button in the terminal window doesn't kill the terminal, it just hides it. Only the shell-menu->"kill terminal" path will close the terminal.
